# In an R table of multi-year events, how can you mark the first occurrence of a different event?

Tags: r, time

I'm working with an R table right now that stores events that take place over multiple years. Each of these events has several related variables. For one of these variable, I want to pull out the first occurrence of it in each event series.

```
events <- c('event1', 'event1', 'event1', 'event1', 'event1', 'event2', 'event2', 'event2')  
years <- c('2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '1994', '1995', '1996') 
variable1 <- c('False', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True')  
df <- data.frame(events, years, variable1)
```

I want to figure out a way to generate a new column, First_occurrence, that looks like this:

```
Event   Year   Variable1   First_occurrence
event1  1994   False       False                              
event1  1995   True        True
event1  1996   True        False
event1  1997   True        False
event2  2000   False       False
event2  2001   False       False
event2  2002   True        True
```

How would I go about creating that "First_occurrence" column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, if you're ok with tidyverse solutions:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 arrange(events,years) %>% 
 group_by(events) %>% 
 mutate(first_occ = row_number() == which(variable1 == 'True')[1])

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   events [2]
  events years variable1 first_occ
   <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <lgl>
1 event1  2000     False     FALSE
2 event1  2001     False     FALSE
3 event1  2002     False     FALSE
4 event1  2003      True      TRUE
5 event1  2004      True     FALSE
6 event2  1994     False     FALSE
7 event2  1995     False     FALSE
8 event2  1996      True      TRUE
```

A small note: stuff like this could potentially be slightly smoother to code if your "True"/"False" variables are actually booleans, rather than character or factors. In that case boolean comparisons are easier and you can leverage the automatic coercion to 1/0 in many cases.

Note that this answer may yield undesirable results if an event has no occurrences at all.

Comment: Thanks! This is great. Just had a thought--would it be possible to create a different column with the number of years past event1's beginning, say, that the occurrence takes place?